# R spatial: st_overlaps to subset also fully covered polygons?

Tags: gdal, r, overlapping-features, sp, rgdal

I want to subset all polygons in `fc1` completely or partially overlapping with `fc2`. But, the `st_overlaps` **subsets only polygons that overlaps with the border of `fc2`, but skips the fully covered polygons**. I.e. here: polygons in center (grey) are not subsetted, only red polygons are returned as overlapped:

[image]

I wonder if **there is a way how to subset all - partially and fully covered - polygons at once**? Is really the only option to subset polygons twice: by `st_covers` and `st_overlaps` and then combine them? Would not this approach lead to duplicated polygons?

My dummy example:

```
# Load data
shp = system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")    
my.sf <- st_read(shp, quiet = TRUE)

# Convert crs to projected system to make buffer
my.sf.web<- st_transform(my.sf, 3857)

# Subset one polygon
i = 10
one  = my.sf.web[i, ]

# Create buffer 
buff50 = st_buffer(one, 50000)

# Check which polygons overlaps with my buffer
out.overlap = st_overlaps(buff50, my.sf.web)

# Subset the polygons that overlaps with the buffer
nbrs.buff.over  <- my.sf.web[st_overlaps(buff50,my.sf.web)[[1]],]
nbrs.buff.cover <- my.sf.web[st_covers(buff50,my.sf.web)[[1]],]

# Merge both spatial subsets:  # !!! Is there easier and less error prone solution??
out <- cbind(nbrs.buff.over, nbrs.buff.cover)
```

I expect that my **output will contain all - completely and fully covered polygons**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *st_intersects()* instead of *st_overlaps()*. You only got 9 features, because *st_overlaps()* does not return features that are completely contained by the other geometry.

```
out.overlap <- my.sf.web[st_intersects(buff50, my.sf.web, sparse =  FALSE),]
```

With this you should have your 11 polygons that you want. In this case the sf-cheat sheet which you can find here: https://rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/ is quite helpful, to exactly now which operation does what.

Comment: Hm @Illundra this is an interesting approach... Forces me to rething what I want to accomplish with my approach... I did not realize that `st_intersect` return full polygons, not just their parts.

Comment: It depends what you are using: `st_intersects` returns TRUE/FALSE if the polygon is intersecting another one. If you only want to have the parts you have to use `st_intersection`

Answer (score 0):

St_intersects() however does also include those polygons, which only share the same boundary with the  polygons of interest. This might not be desired. So indeed, there is a spatial operation missing, which combines st_covers and st_overlaps and returns those polygons, which are fully or partly covered by y polygons (and the spatial overlay does not change geometry type, e.g. as in intersecting polygon boundaries are linestring)